# Splitting the tag [firebase-cloud-firestore] from [google-cloud-firestore]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I realised there isn't a tag for **Firebase Cloud Firestore** which most of the questions related are under the tag of **google-cloud-firestore**.  Although Firebase Cloud Firestore is under Firebase which is the subsidiary of Google, it is still  under different products.

> Firebase is Google's mobile development platform. Helps you build apps
>   and grow your user base.
>
> Used by client-side app developers (both web & mobile).
>
> Used for building a new mobile app, augmenting an existing app with
>   new functionality and growing an audience.
>
> Google Cloud Platform (GCP) is a suite of cloud computing services.
>   Makes Google's infrastructure (Compute, Storage, Networking, Data
>   Analytics, and Machine Learning) publicly available as composable
>   services.
>
> Used by backend & server-side developers.
>
> Used for building software leveraging Google's core infrastructure,
>   data analytics, and machine learning.

Based on the products description, Firebase is focus on mobile while GCP focus on cloud computing services.

So I propose to split the tag into 2 different tags as I realised a lot of problems are mobile related.  Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any point in splitting these tags as this is a single product.

I admit the naming can be confusing and suggest reversing the synonym:

[firebase-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-firestore) --> [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore)

Instead of the current

[firebase-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-firestore) <-- [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore)

Comment: Both focus different fields (one on mobile and one on cloud computing) and even their billing plans are different.  Just like Toyota 86 and Subaru BRZ, even they have similar outlook and spec sheet but they are still under different branding.  If a firebase cloud firestore has problem, they will be finding Firebase team and not the Google team as Firebase user only subscribe to Firebase plan.

Comment: @AngusTay The only difference is the words used to describe it on the two web pages. As for billing both sites are exactly the same: [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) and [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing).

Comment: What I mean is that firebase pay to Firebase and not Google while GCP user pay to Google not Firebase.

Comment: @AngusTay It really doesn't matter where the money goes for the tag on stackoverflow. My point is that it's a single product (Firestore) and it doesn't matter if you use it for mobile or something else. The code used is exactly the same and it is most effective to have a single tag. And here is a car explenation: You can use your Toyota 86 to go to your work or tour the world but it doesn't matter to the mechanic how you use it to be able to help you fix it. (Or do you need a different mechanic for both situations?)